# How to Run the Appium Selenium Mobile Automated Script on remote/another machine from main code machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-grid, android-uiautomator, appium-android

How to run the Appium Mobile automation script from one main/coding machine to another machine where other machine have connected device.

I want to know the software/prerequisites required for running the code on other machine and also the process for setting up the same.

Currently I have designed and running Appium Mobile automation code on my local machine (source code machine) for testing with real device. So my requirement is, that when I run the code from my local machine it should get executed on another machine which is connected with device.

things used for Mobile Automation:

1. Appium Desktop system
2. Android SDK
3. Appium client
4. Seleenium client
5. Real devices connected to machine

Answer (score 1):

you can connect devices over TCP/IP and set desired_caps udid like this

desired_caps['udid'] = 'IP:PORT'